# How do I expose subscription only content to search engine crawl agents in an MVC3 app?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, seo

I have a small and simple Learning Management System (LMS), where authors write course modules, and clients purchase these modules for employee training. I'm guessing e.g. Google will crawl Index pages, and follow links to individual content pages. There is no Index page with URL's to all content, so I'm thinking I should create a separate search only index that includes a url to an excerpt view for every item of course content.

Am I on the right track? What is the conventional way of exposing dynamic content in an MVC3 app to search crawlers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple method would be a sitemap.  It's a simple XML document that you could generate dynamically to tell Google where to go.

Here's some [documentation from Google](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156184)

There are numerous generators out there that can do the work for you, but it's a piece of cake writing one yourself.

Another method might be an index of lessons that serves not only google, but also allows your users to find content of interest.  As long as you've got links on that page, Google will pick them up.  Using good quality content descriptions will help your cause.

Obviously, inbound links from other sites directly to lessons will also help your cause if you allow it, but don't try to cheat the system by "seeding" links all over the web in places they don't belong, that's sleazy SEO.

Finally, remember that if you have things password protected, it's a definite block to Google.  Ensure that if you are trying to get Google to "know" about something that's password protected that you provide a descriptive, non-passworded page in addition to the protected content.